# Multiple Line of Text field triggers Workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: designer-workflow, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a field named **Comments** which is a Multiple Lines of Text (Plain text). In SharePoint Designer I have created a workflow which triggers an email based on certain criteria.

The issue is when I update some value in that Comments field and click anywhere on the form (it's designed in Infopath) the workflow is getting triggered even without hitting the Submit button.

I am not sure how the Workflow is getting triggered this way. Please help.

Comment: What is the criteria? Open the form and right click on the control and go to the properties. Change "Send values to server" to never. Each time you enter a value and click somewhere outside the control, the value is sent to the server and it might be this that trigger your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of clicking anywhere on the form trigger the workflow, that mean the submit action is fired so maybe you have a **submit rule** that executed after changing the value of the comments field.

So try to review your control rules and make sure that you didn't have a submit rule for any other controls otherwise the save button.